# Add audio when Splash Screen starts on Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, splash-screen

I have created an installer with inno setup, I have also managed to place a splash screen and I have also managed to add a sound to the installation wizard.

What I really need is to make the audio that I have added can be playad when the Splash Screen starts.

My audio code:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[ISSI]
;; Name of the bitmap image:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Program\Splash\SPLASH.bmp"

;; Time in seconds:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen_T 10

;; Image Width:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen_X 700

;; Image Heigth:
#define ISSI_SplashScreen_Y 169

;; Rounded corners (Optional):
#define ISSI_Splash_Corner

;; Include ISSI (required)
#define ISSI_IncludePath "C:\ISSI"
#include ISSI_IncludePath+"\_issi.isi"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Program\Splash\isgsg.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Program\Splash\IsUtilsHb.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Program\Splash\SPLASH.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Code]
const  
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;
  BASS_UNICODE = $80000000;
  BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM = 5;
const
  #ifndef UNICODE
    EncodingFlag = 0;
  #else
    EncodingFlag = BASS_UNICODE;
  #endif
type
  HSTREAM = DWORD;

function BASS_Init(device: LongInt; freq, flags: DWORD; 
  win: HWND; clsid: Cardinal): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Init@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: BOOL; f: string; offset1: DWORD; 
  offset2: DWORD; length1: DWORD; length2: DWORD; flags: DWORD): HSTREAM;
  external 'BASS_StreamCreateFile@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: BOOL): BOOL; 
  external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_SetConfig(option: DWORD; value: DWORD ): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_SetConfig@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Free: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Free@files:bass.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  StreamHandle: HSTREAM;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('AudioFile.mp3');
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    StreamHandle := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, 
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AudioFile.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
    BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);
    BASS_ChannelPlay(StreamHandle, False);
  end;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  BASS_Free;
end;
```

This is the code that I tried according to the explanation of martin

```
[Code]
function ISSI_InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  StreamHandle: HSTREAM;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('AudioFile.mp3');
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    StreamHandle := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, 
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AudioFile.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
    BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);
    BASS_ChannelPlay(StreamHandle, False);
  end;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  BASS_Free;
end; 

  Result := True;
end;
[/Code]
```

Ok...

Comment: I have already added it, in a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this way:

```
#define ISSI_InitializeSetup

[Code]
const  
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;
  BASS_UNICODE = $80000000;
  BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM = 5;
const
  #ifndef UNICODE
    EncodingFlag = 0;
  #else
    EncodingFlag = BASS_UNICODE;
  #endif
type
  HSTREAM = DWORD;

function BASS_Init(device: LongInt; freq, flags: DWORD; 
  win: HWND; clsid: Cardinal): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Init@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: BOOL; f: string; offset1: DWORD; 
  offset2: DWORD; length1: DWORD; length2: DWORD; flags: DWORD): HSTREAM;
  external 'BASS_StreamCreateFile@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: BOOL): BOOL; 
  external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_SetConfig(option: DWORD; value: DWORD ): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_SetConfig@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Free: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Free@files:bass.dll stdcall';

function ISSI_InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
  StreamHandle: HSTREAM;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('AudioFile.mp3');
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    StreamHandle := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, 
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AudioFile.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
    BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);
    BASS_ChannelPlay(StreamHandle, False);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
[/Code]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer louis, I still have errors when compiling, I think I will have to abandon this question and look for other ways, thank you very much for having answered.

Comment: I will try to help you, can you show me the compilation error?

Comment: thanks, is working great! Finally, what should I do so that the music does not repeat itself? just once